# C language- is there a function like isdigit() but can verify whether char contains double?

Tags: c

I am trying to verify whether my input has `double` number or not.

using `isdigit()` function can verify number 0~9 but can't verify `double` number such as `0.1`, `0.5` or `0.771`.

Is there another function? if not, how can I make this work?

Comment: Research `strtod()`.

Comment: @sylphes A character can not contain a double.:)

Comment: A single character (e.g. `char c;`) can only contain a single digit that could be valid as a `double`.  If you want to check a character string (an array of one or more characters terminated by a null byte), use [`strtod()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtod.html) as suggested already.  The `ispqrst()` functions in `<ctypes.h>` (such as `isdigit()`) all work with a single character at a time.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow He obviously means "a character valid in a double", the way that `isdigit()` tests if the character is valid in a positive integer.

Comment: @Barmar: That is not at all obvious. Such an `isdouble` function would return true for each character in “3.4.5”, but this would not satisfy the stated goal “to verify whether my input has double number or not.”

Comment: You can use `strtod()` or `sscanf()`.

Answer (score 3):

A `char` is only a single *digit*, but a *string* may contain several characters that can be interpreted as a `double`.

```
// Return 1 if a double found _somewhere_ in the string.
int verify_whether_string_contains_double(const char *s) {
  while (*s) {
    char *endptr;

    // Return the double (which we do not save)
    strtod(s, &endptr);
    // If `endptr1 the same as `s`, no conversion occurred.
  
    if (endptr > s) {
      return 1; // a portion of the string successfully converts to a double
    }
    s++; // try again at the next char
  }
  return 0; // No part of the string contains a double.
}
```

Usage:

```
char buf[100];
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
if (verify_whether_string_contains_double(buf)) {
  puts("double found");
} else {
  puts("double not found");
}
```

---

If we want to detect if the whole *string* contains text that converts to a `double` and no extra junk:

```
int verify_whether_string_contains_only_double(const char *s) {
  char *endptr;

  strtod(s, &endptr);
  if (endptr == s) {
    return 0; // No conversion
  }

  // look for trailing junk
  // Let us allow trailing white-space.
  while (isspace(*(unsigned char*)endptr)) {
    endptr++;
  }

  return *endptr == '\0';  // Success if we end at the string end.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple alternative to `strtod()` to check if a string contains the representation of a number:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// check if s contains a number with optional initial and trailing whitespace
int isnumber(const char *s) {
    double d;
    char c;
    return sscanf(s, "%lf %c", &d, &c) == 1;
}
```

Comment: Interesting given spec's "if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behavior is undefined.".  With integer conversions, this readily can result in UB, but with FP, I do not see if UB is possible unless _infinity_ does not exist. for the implementation's `double`. Nice.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: interestingly, the result of most conversions from decimal floating point representations cannot be exactly represented as `double` values, even within the range of this type, so the possibilities for undefined behavior are immense. For values beyond the range of the target type, `Infinity` is not an exact or even close representation either, but *undefined behavior* covers this possibility.  It would be better if the Standard used *implementation defined* instead.